# CSS: Border with border-radius has bad quality

Tags: css

I want to know how can I fix the border of this play button. It has `1px` of border and `50%` border-radius, and it looks ugly. 2px looks ok but I need 1.

[image]

Comment: could there be other properties causing this? or maybe the screen resolution?

Comment: LOL, it is all screen resolution, even if you use a `img` with a 1px wide border you will still see it that way. no - fix possible.

Comment: so even this sample looks bad when you view it? http://jsfiddle.net/u2j3nLqo/

Answer (score 5):

Same questions solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135196/css-1px-border-stroke-breaks-around-border-radius) by Guy.

This is common when having a background and a border specified. The only way to fix this would be to have two separate elements, one with the background color and one with the border color with padding equal to the border-width.

See [this article](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2011/08/border-radius-rendering/) for a better explanation.

or try `box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0px @yourBlueColor inset, 0 0 1px 0px @yourBlueColor;`

Comment: I don't have a background specified

Comment: box-shadow even solves the issue, but doesn't look that great. But I don't think we have any other to solve that...

Answer (score 2):

this problem is correlated to resolution dpi of your screen device , you can fix this with

```
border: 2px solid rgba(42, 91, 195, 0.35);
```

use 2px but use also a rgba transparent effect for reduce the size of border

Answer (score 1):

Not great, but looks quite a lot better by setting besides the border at 1px, an inset box-shadow with 1px blur-radius of the same color:

```
border: 1px solid #333;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #333;
```